# Execution failed for task ':android:mergeDexDebug' when implementing another module

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx

I am getting an error when trying to run my android libgdx application.

I tried setting multidex to true but that just brings different problems. Also invalidated my cache. When removing the line to implement "client_core" it starts working. I am programming in IntelliJ.

build.gradle of android module

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.unkn0wn.pong"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    implementation project(":client_core") //Commenting this line out "fixes" the problem
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:1.9.10"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.10:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.10:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.10:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.10:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:1.9.10:natives-x86_64"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:1.9.10:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:1.9.10:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:1.9.10:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:1.9.10:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:1.9.10:natives-x86_64"
}
...
```

build.gradle of client_core module

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':core')
    implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:1.9.10"
}
```

Getting following errors when trying to run in IntelliJ on an emulator or real phone:

```
Execution failed for task ':android:mergeDexDebug'
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':android:debugRuntimeClasspath'
Failed to transform artifact 'client_core.jar (project :client_core)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=18, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=11, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars}
Execution failed for DexingTransform: /home/marcel/Dokumente/Pong/client_core/build/libs/client_core.jar
```